# Ruta de la Tabla que almacena los Procedimientos Almacenados en MySql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Necesito migrar de servidor la base de datos, y para esto necesito saber cual es la ruta de la tabla que almacena los Procedimientos almacenados...

Comment: Si vas a migrar la base completa por qué no haces un respaldo completo y lo montas en el servidor destino? o cómo va a ser tu migración.

Comment: estoy en un entorno wamp, migrare a otra maquina wamp.  solo necesito sacar la BD que esta en la ruta wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data\mybd pero lo que no tengo claro es en que tabla se almacenan los procedimientos.. esto es a modo de solamente tomar las carpetas necesarias y no estar tomando lo innecesario.

Comment: Francis ¿no basta con hacer un backup de la bd en cuestión y restaurarla con todo?

Comment: necesito solamente saber de que forma identifico la tabla que almacena los SP

Answer (score -1):

Solo debes respaldar lo que esta en la carpeta 
`wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/data/base_de_datos_a_respaldar`, ahí en la carpeta data se encuentran todas las **bd** y sus elementos, debes copiarla nada más.

Te recomiendo que instalar un programa que te permita respaldar de una manera más efectiva las bases de datos tanto para exportar como importar en formato .sql ejemplo (`SQLyog Enterprise`).

Comment: Estimado, es lo que hago , pero lamentablemente de esta forma no se traspasan los SP